# how to run server side javascript in client browser

Tags: javascript, serverside-javascript

can you help me how to run server side java-script and how to configure server. please give me link or step by step process how to perform this action because no one are give the exact solution

Comment: *"how to run server side javascript in client browser"* makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

the only server side javascript I know of is node.js, however even that is off limits to client side scripts for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

> how to run server side javascript in client browser

You can't. That is why it is called **server side** JavaScript. The server executes the JavaScript and delivers the output to the client, which never sees the server side side.

> can you help me how to run server side java-script and how to configure server.

Both depend on which type of SSJS you are using (so we can't provide specific instructions without more information or by making assumptions). [Node](http://nodejs.org/) is probably the most popular option at present. They have plenty of documentation (including some quick start guides on the front page of their site).

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, take a look at [node.js](http://nodejs.org/). You will find instructions on to install and run node.js, and there are examples as well.